NSCollectionLayoutItem created with invalid combination of spacing and size specified
I am using UICollection View Compositional Layout to calculate the items and groups
i encountered this error
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout: 0x15f37c680> ran into an error when computing the layout for section at index 23 in container. <_UICollectionLayoutContainer: 0x30265eec0 contentSize={390, 620}; contentInsets={0, 0, 0, 0}}>.

 Container calculated by applying insets ({0, 0, 0, 0}) from sectionInsetsReference "safeArea" to collection view frame {{0, 110}, {390, 620}}.

Error: NSCollectionLayoutItem created with invalid combination of spacing and size specified. This group cannot fit even a single item. Inspect the spacing and size of the items in this group and ensure that they fit into the group when its effective size is {358, 36}.
Group: <NSCollectionLayoutGroup 0x300abf700 size={ .absolute(358), .absolute(36)} >
     layoutDirection: .horizontal
     interItemSpacing = .fixed(10)
         subitems = <NSCollectionLayoutItem 0x3018d3de0 size={ .estimated(30), .absolute(36)}>'

i got this error but i don't totally understand it, why I don't understand?

the group effective size is {358, 36} , the item size is {30,36} then why it is not able to fit a single item?? although the item width is much less the groups width

// the envWidth is set from UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout closure
let envWidth = env.container.contentSize.width - 32

    static func ReviewerTagsCellCompositionalLayout(envWidth: CGFloat) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        let leadingInset : CGFloat = 16
        let trailingInset : CGFloat = 16
        // Define the size for each item
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(30), heightDimension: .absolute(36))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        // Create a horizontal group with multiple items in the same row
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(envWidth), heightDimension: .absolute(36))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems:[item])
        
        // Adjust the inter-item spacing if needed
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(10)

        // Create the section
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 10
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: leadingInset, bottom: 30, trailing: trailingInset)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .none

        return section
}any possible solutions? 

what i tried ?

giving the group an absolute width from environment also from UIWindow!
tried removing the spacing of the group in sections and the items in the group


The error indicate that your itemSize is bigger than groupSize so you should upload your UICollectionViewCell code for more debug information.

do u want to see how the nib file looks like ?

yes, it even better if you can provide a minimal produce example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
